# How to fix Windows 8 statup and remove Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-8, uninstall

The Dualboot is not working, so I want to get rid of Ubuntu.

I think the problem has something to do with UEFI / Legacy, But I have given up now and acceptet that Ubuntu is still for IT Experts only.

My problem is that if I startup in boot manager, It will not startup Windows.

Comment: "How to uninstall Ubuntu 14.04 from Windows 8" will not fix "It will not startup Windows.".

Answer (score 0):

try restoring the MBR of windows 8, using the fixmbr tool that comes with windows install, maybe this way you can boot windows normally and then delete the partitions of ubuntu from there, i had a similar issue with dual boot win7-ubuntu, here is a link to tutorial for restoring the MBR 
http://www.redmondpie.com/how-to-fix-windows-8-mbr-master-boot-record
or asuming you use grub(ubuntu default) as boot manager
you can try entering ubuntu, opening the terminal(control+alt+t) and typing "sudo update-grub", check if after this you can see windows 8 in the grub boot menu

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you are ready to get rid of Ubuntu permanently-

- You need Windows 8 boot disk or bootable USB atleast (must).
- Put it in tray and boot into Windows. Now choose "Repair Windows" option when the Windows installation window appears.
- It detects Windows 8 if its already in HDD. Now choose "Command prompt".
- Now type this commands serially - `bootrec/fixmbr`
  `bootrec/fixboot`
- Additionally you can type in `sfc/scannow` for integration errors.
- Thats it. Now GRUB menu will be erased and you can boot into Windows directly if everything goes right.
- So in Windows you can delete Ubuntu partition from Windows partition manager.

*Comment if anything goes wrong.*